# DiscordJS - Counting more than what he should [NODE-JS]

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Here is my script:

```
let deleted_roles_counter = 0

    console.log("Deleting roles...")
    message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(roles => {
        roles.delete()
        .then(deleted_roles_counter++)
        .catch(e => {e})
    });
    console.log(`Deleted ${deleted_roles_counter} roles`)
```

I have 3 roles, the bot role (which is not deletable), the @everyone role (which is not either) and the role : New Role (which is deletable)

Now as you can see on the .then their is a counter, but the counter count the 3 roles instead of just the role that have been deleted (New Role) [1]

I've also tried to put deleted_roles_counter - 1 in the catch but this don't more either

Would one of you have the idea for how to change this?

Comment: `.then( () => deleted_roles_counter++ )` as the quickfix. In your current code, the increment is called no matter what happens in the `delete()` before.

Comment: that's not working, this is counting me 0 every time

Comment: then I'd log the actual errors and not just swallow them.

Comment: sidenote: are you sure that those calls are all synchronous? seems somewhat unlikely for a remote service. if they are asynchronous then maybe it's just a matter of race conditions between your output and the remaining code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to add if statement before you call the `.delete()` to check if the role is bot role or `@everyone` role.

```
let deleted_roles_counter = 0
console.log("Deleting roles...")
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(roles => {
   if(!roles.managed || roles.id !== guild.roles.everyone.id || roles.editable){ 
       roles.delete()
       .then(deleted_roles_counter++)
       .catch(e => {e})
   }
});
console.log(`Deleted ${deleted_roles_counter} roles`)
```

`.managed` returns a boolean whether or not the role is managed by an external service (bot), and the second one is self-explanatory, it checks if the role is `@everyone`

Comment: yess... but no, the roles that are higher than the bot's role will not be able to be deleted

Comment: Just add another condition to the if check `roles.editable` it returns boolean whether bot can edit the role aka delete it. If it cant edit the role, it cant delete role, simple

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is not working? Saying "not working" is really not that helpful :-/

Comment: the change you told me to do, don't solve the problem, it does the exact same thing